# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem inside foreach use same dataset

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, parallel.foreach

In the function below always the same `user` object is passed to the `DoRestCall` method

(I do have logging in the `DoRestCall` method and it has the same first data in the `user` object)
Do I need to use Parallel.ForEach instead of Threadpool

```
private void CreateUser(DataServiceCollection<User> epUsers)
{
    foreach (User user in epUsers)
    {
        try
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(f =>
            {
                DoRestCall(string.Format("MESSAGE-TYPE=UserEnrollmentCreate&PAYLOAD={0}",
                                         GenarateRequestUserData(user)), true);
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("Error in CreateUser " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're making REST call, why use the `ThreadPool` for I/O bound work? Which version of the .NET framework are you using

Comment: Ys i'm making rest call any drawbacks ? C# and .net4.0

Comment: Yes. You allocate a ThreadPool threads just to block waiting for the REST call to return, it is a waste of resources.

Comment: Any alternative for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how loop variables are handled when used in a lambda expression or anonymous methods. The lambda expression sees the current value of the loop variable at the time the lambda is executed. I believe this behaviour was changed in C# 5.0, but haven't tried it yet.

You need to store the current user in a variable inside the foreach loop and use that instead of the loop variable (also, your try / catch doesn't catch any exceptions inside your `WaitCallback`, see fix below):

```
foreach (User user in epUsers)
{
    User currentUser = user;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(f =>
    {
        try
        {
            DoRestCall(string.Format("MESSAGE-TYPE=UserEnrollmentCreate&PAYLOAD={0}",
                                     GenarateRequestUserData(currentUser)), true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("Error in CreateUser " + ex.Message);
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: `foreach` was changed in C# 5.0, `for` was not, so you're entirely right on all counts.